# Display multiple image from server folder at one time in JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm having a problem to retrieve and display all image from server folder. I already be able to upload images and store in server folder. However, I cant figure out how to retrieve all images in uploaded folder at one time. Here I attach my code. Really hope any of you to help me out.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>File Upload Example in JSP and Servlet - Java web application</title>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <div id="result">
            <h3>${requestScope["message"]}</h3>
        </div>

        <%
            List imageUrlList = new ArrayList();
            File imageDir = new File("D:\\mywork\\UploadImageDemo\\web\\Upload");
            for (File imageFile : imageDir.listFiles()) {
                String imageFileName = imageFile.getName();

                // add this images name to the list we are building up  
                imageUrlList.add(imageFileName);

            }
            request.setAttribute("imageUrlList", imageUrlList);
        %>

    <c:forEach var="img" items="${imageUrlList}">  
        <img src="${imageUrlList}"/>  
    </c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the Upload folder within your web app's root folder? If it is then, you could try prependlng the src attribute of the images with  "/yourWebAppName/Upload/" or just  "Upload/"

Comment: really appreciate it, thanks

Comment: Were you successful?

Answer (score 0):

JSP is a part of view layer, so you should not insert any Java code there. Only HTML with JSP tags. You should have controllers that will take care of downloading/uploading images, and just use `img` tags for showing images

Look here:
http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/07/fileservlet.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your info